# Convert binaryData to ToBase64String in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, sql

how to convert binarydata to Base64String

i have binary data like `0x89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D49484452000000C800000096080200000014BE504E0000000373424954050605330B8D800,...............`
how to get this data from database string format. ()
how to convert this format to base64

```
 <img runat="server" src ="data:image/png;base64,U3lzdGVtLkJ5dGVbXQ==" />
```

Comment: [Convert.ToBase64String(`byte[]`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx) ??

Comment: Do you have the data as byte[] or only in the HEX representation (string) like you showed in your question?

Comment: i got this error "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it "contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.

Comment: i have data in varbinar(MAX) in database ,how to convert in c#

Comment: How do you get your data from the database? SqlDataReader or some other ADO.NET call?

Comment: SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                GeoMAp GeoMAp = new GeoMAp();
               
                GeoMAp.imageSize = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(reader["ImageSize"].ToString());
                
                lstGeoMAp.Add(GeoMAp);
            }

Comment: i got base64string (U3lzdGVtLkJ5dGVbXQ==)

Comment: <img runat="server" src ="data:image/png;base64,U3lzdGVtLkJ5dGVbXQ==" /> but this not display image

Comment: i have to show image like <img runat="server" src ="data:image/png;base64,U3lzdGVtLkJ5dGVbXQ==" />

Comment: Check this out: http://www.webcodeexpert.com/2014/03/how-to-uploadstore-image-into-sql.html#.Uymh7PldU40

Comment: thumbs up @BrockHensley ..thanks alot